# 7 seats in a row, probability of the married couple sitting together

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So I've figured out that there are $7 \choose 2$ = $21$ possible seat pairings for the couple, and 6 of them result in sitting together, so the probability of them sitting together is $\frac 27$.

However, why doesn't order matter here? Isn't a seat pairing with husband/wife in seat 1/2 respectively, different than them being in seats 2/1 respectively?

Also, why don't we need to account for all the ways the other 5 people could arrange themselves?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order matters then then are $7\times 6 = 42$ ways of sitting the wife then the husband.  There are then $5! = 120$ ways of sitting the other people, making $7!=5040$ ways of seating everybody

Of these, there $2 \times 6=12$ ways of seating the wife and husband together when order matters, or $2 \times 6!=1440$ ways if you also count the other people

All these approaches give the same answer, as $\dfrac{6}{21}=\dfrac{12}{42}=\dfrac{1440}{5040}=\dfrac{2}{7}$

The important thing is keep a consistent method of counting equally probable results for the numerator and denominator

Comment: Ah, I see, so it's all about consistency. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a dumb followup, but is there an obvious way to know when order doesn't matter? In this case I got caught up in thinking about the ways the other people could be arranged, but that clearly wasn't necessary.

Comment: Since you can say there are $42$ equally probable ways of seating the couple of which $12$ have them sitting together, you can ignore the other people.  The $5!$ different ways the other people can be seated after the couple is sitting down can be left out of both numerator and denominator because they do not affect the "equal probability" part of the counting calculation

Answer (score 0):

Say $\Omega_1$ is the probability space consisting of the possible orderings of distinct people and each ordering has the same probability. What you did is to map this space to $\Omega_2$ where we forget the identity of the individuals and only distinguish between the married pair and the rest. So for instance $\Omega_2$ consists of all the orderings of 2 red and 5 blue marbles, if you will.

Say person 1 and 2 are married, then

$$ \phi : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2 $$

$$ (5,3,2,6,4,1,7) \mapsto (B,B,R,B,B,R,B) $$

Via $\phi$, the probability measure on $\Omega_1$ induces a measure on $\Omega_2$; but it turns out this measure is the SAME as the uniform distribution on $\Omega_2$.

This is because each preimage $\phi^{-1}((B,B,R,B,B,R;B))$ has the same size, namely $2\cdot 5 = 10$, and therefore the same probability.

Anti-example: Due to unfortunate circumstances the last two seats in the row explode. What is the probability of the couple sitting together now?

One guess is: $\frac{4}{\binom{5}{0} + \binom{5}{1} + \binom{5}{2}}$, i.e. either one or two of the spouses got blown up, or both are alive with 5 seats left. But this is not the right answer: Let $\Omega_3$ be the set of possible orderings of red and blue marbles after the explosion.
The map $\Omega_2 \mapsto \Omega_3, (x_1,...,x_7) \mapsto (x_1,...,x_6)$ has preimages of cardinality 1 or 2, so the above answer is not correct.